# What do you call a visual language based on color frequency?

Tags: linguistic-typology, evolution

I was thinking about [this question and answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66270/how-expressive-is-a-color-based-language/66276#66276) about how cephalopods might develop a language, in this case a visual one.

How would linguistics term a language that is communicated visually as a cycling of colors?

For example, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcpzubpIhtI) shows a cuttlefish using a rapid cycling of skin color to aid it in capturing it's prey.

Now let's say cuttlefish began to use their color changing ability to develop a language based on frequency of skin color change. What kind of language would that be? What would linguists call it?

Comment: VOR is a science fiction novel by James Blish, 1958, in which the first alien we encounter apparently speaks a color language.  Its name is violet-orange-red, as I recall.

Comment: No such natural language currently exists, so there is no standard term.

Comment: @GregLee I'm new here. Do you know why people keep downvoting my question? Am I using terminology incorrectly? Or is my question just too ignorant to be considered a good question for this site?

Comment: Personally, I don't participate in this business of policing the asking of questions -- I don't approve of it.  So I'm  not a good one to ask.  About your question, it's not really a linguistic question, since you're just asking for a term.  It might be interesting to ask what a color language would be *like*, but who cares what it would be *called*?

Comment: @GregLee I'm interested in what it would be called because I'd like to google it and read about it, but I can't find a term to google.

Comment: @GregLee [This video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZM0zS5MRRA&t=0m24s) seems to me to show a very clear pattern of communication using colors and tentacle positions, which seems to me to mean cuttlefish have a language, but I can't figure out why that form of communication has no name in linguistics. The cuttle fish is definitely attempting to communicate aggression and hostility in the beginning, but not later on in the video.

Comment: @GregLee [This video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=i-acel62ePc) also seems to show distinctive communication via tentacle positions, color patterns and body position. Do you agree?

Comment: @GregLee But in [this video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RFgs0hA0eS0&t=1m52s) the cuttlefish is all golden yellow when it's feeling very friendly. Actually it looks quite beautiful, as opposed to the other menacing colors in the other videos.

Comment: I have no opinion about the video.  There have been controversies about whether animal communication systems should count as "language", so I'd be cautious using the term.

Comment: @GregLee Ah! Ok thank you, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess ***visuo-chromatic*** (or perhaps ***visuo-pigmental***) would be the proper term. You can mostly hear about *audio-oral* languages or forms of communication, occasionally also about *visuo-gestural* ones (sign languages) or even *tactile* ones (sign languages for deaf-blind people).

Comment: Can you provide any links to a description of this system of categorizing languages? Like, what terms are available to concatenate for creating these terms? Or, is it just something informally constructed? Or did you just invent this?

Comment: I do not believe there is any closed bank of such terms and they are coined based on necessity (which does not arise very often to be honest, there are only so many ways people communicate with each other). The most frequent one by far is _audio-oral_, I have not heard/read _visuo-gestural_ more than twice. In any case, you can see that this is constructed as _[method of perceiving]-[method of producing]_, so you just pick the right Latin/Greek words. Now that I think of it - _visuo-pigmental_ might be even more proper in case of skin colour change.